# Import Maven dependancies into Java project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am trying to learn a new framework ([Blade](https://github.com/lets-blade/blade#quick-start)) for Java, following the Quick Start guide, and trying to import with Maven (which I am also unfamiliar with):

When I add the dependencies to Netbeans, they show up but the main class that the Quick Start guide instructs to use `com.blade.Blade` is unimportable:

[image]

How do I import the class file from the Maven dependencies list?

Here's a look at the `pom.xml` just incase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bladejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>blade-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.11.BETA</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bladejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>blade-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11.BETA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans but if the dependencies are correctly imported (did you do it or did Netbeans create the Dependencies folder?) you should be fine. What message do you get (especially since only the "com"-part seems to be the problem)?

Comment: I did not find the Blade class, using the search field on [mvnrepository.com ...](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bladejava/blade/1.1.3), Maybe as sample not in maven?

Comment: Netbeans imported them when I added the `<dependencies>` section on the `pom.xml`

Comment: Netbeans has a clever search too, maybe there were more than one option and the wrong one was selected. Delete the dependencies and start over

Comment: you pom.xml GAV is the same of the declared dependency, that will cause havoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added just "blade-mvc" dependency, I think you try to add "blade-core":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bladejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>blade-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.11.BETA</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bladejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>blade-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.11.BETA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bladejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>blade-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok, that worked to make `import com.blade.Blade;` import, but the Quick Start says to use a method `Blade.of() ...` but that doesn't work. Also, how did you know to add the core dependency?